# Make for doxygen enum inside group fail error

Tags: pdf, enums, doxygen, miktex

I have some C code that uses doxygen to document it.

If I try and document the values of an enum that is inside a group the doxygen build runs OK, *BUT* the pdf make produces errors

> The General Purpose Indexer has stopped working

With the option to either close the program or debug it. Selecting close, allows the make to continue, until the next pass, where the same error occurs again, currently this uses about 3 passes.

The PDF produced however, *does* contian the enum documentation and so far, with my small little C project, the PDF seems OK appearance-wise.

With the enum outside of the group, the error disappears...

All my documentation toolchain is checked upto date (doxygen, MiKTex, GPL GhostScript).
Has anyone seen similar or have a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the git version of doxygen, here Bug 733323 - Doxygen generated LaTeX leads to General Purpose Index Processor crash (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=733323) has been integrated.

Comment: `make` on windowz :(. Thanks Albert

Comment: Any idea when a binary may be released for Win with this?
Also I note the following may be related
http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2144/